# How to intermix dataframes in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider two pandas DataFrames with a similar structure:

DataFrame A

```
   Id      Time  Value
0   1  12:40:00      0
1   2  12:40:00     70
2   3  12:40:00      0
3   4  12:40:00     70
4   5  12:40:01     20
5   6  12:40:01     90
```

DataFrame B

```
     Id      Time  Value
0  1001  12:40:00    200
1  1002  12:40:00    500
2  1003  12:40:00    600
3  1004  12:40:01    600
4  1005  12:40:01    800
5  1006  12:40:01    700
```

I'm looking for a way to concatenate (or intermix) these DataFrames preserving relative order of the items:

1. All entries of the resulting DataFrame must be sorted with respect to Time column
2. Entries from one DataFrame should preserve their relative order in each Time group, but allow items from other DataFrames among them
3. Besides that, I need the items from each original DataFrame to be randomly distributed in each Time group

So I expect the resulting DataFrame to look like this:

```
      Id      Time  Value
 0  1001  12:40:00    200
 1     1  12:40:00      0
 2     2  12:40:00     70
 3  1002  12:40:00    500
 4     3  12:40:00      0
 5     4  12:40:00     70
 6  1003  12:40:00    600
 7  1004  12:40:01    600
 8     5  12:40:01     20
 9  1005  12:40:01    800
10  1006  12:40:01    700
11     6  12:40:01     90
```

`pd.concat((df_A, df_B)).sort_values(by='Time')` produces the combined DataFrame but without mixing:

```
         Id      Time  Value
    0     1  12:40:00      0
    1     2  12:40:00     70
    2     3  12:40:00      0
    3     4  12:40:00     70
    0  1001  12:40:00    200
    1  1002  12:40:00    500
    2  1003  12:40:00    600
    4     5  12:40:01     20
    5     6  12:40:01     90
    3  1004  12:40:01    600
    4  1005  12:40:01    800
    5  1006  12:40:01    700
```

So my question is how to finally transform this DataFrame to the expected form? I have encountered implementation of this where entries were iteratively inserted into resulting DataFrame using custom generator yielding them in a specific order, however it was very time inefficient and I will need to use this transformation on tens of GBs of data on regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
pd.concat((df_A, df_B)).groupby('Time', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=1)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: This solution has a flaw of breaking of consecutive order of entries in each subgroup from one of the original dataframe.